# How do I correctly identify the purpose of a wire?

Tags: wiring, uk, phone-wiring, internet

I have recently moved into a new home. When I tried to have internet set up, I realized there was no phone/internet socket.

I eventually realized that there were four TV/aerial sockets next to each other in the one room, which struck me as quite odd. I unscrewed the covers on the sockets to discover that there were only 2 wires (despite 4 plug holes!) and neither were attached to the covers as you would expect them to be.

Based on the fact that all the other flats in the building have TV and phone connections I have assumed that one of these is a TV cable and one is a phone cable.

How can I identify which is which? Or even if my assumption is correct?

I am in the UK.

Comment: Can you post photos?

Comment: How old is the home there have been many different types of outlets over the years for telephone outlets.

Comment: "all the other flats" call the building manager, done.  It may be your **home** spiritually, but in terms of bailiwicks of responsibility for shared infrastructure that must be punched down to a central board, it's their **facility**.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel they are currently behidn a hevay piano but i will try to get a photo.

Comment: @EdBeal the building is 1910ish. i have no idea when it was turned into flats, but it was completely refurbed in the last 12 months. However there is no socket... just 2 wires...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, identify the type of socket.  This is a typical UK media socket faceplate as used in new-build houses:

[image: Multi-socket Faceplate]

The two sockets to the top left are for RF satellite - usually used in pairs.
Below this, from left to right:
UHF (Terrestrial TV)
DAB Radio
UHF Return (Used to send signals from a TV set-top box to another room)
BT Telephone / Broadband

You will have one or more of these sockets on your faceplate.

If you have a cable service such as Virgin Media, it will use one of the RF sockets in place of the satellite TV.

Your internet will either be on the BT socket - a multi-core cable, or the RF socket - a single-core cable.

Note that UHF cables are significantly thicker than RF cables, that should help you identify them.

Comment: Thank you Chenmuka, but there is no socket... there are jsut 2 wires in the wall. i want to try to attach a socket to the wire btu can't do so until i know which wire is which...